# En «Piedad a mi llanto» y «Ten piedad de mi llanto» se deben usar necesariamente las preposiciones «a» y «de» en cada caso?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, preposiciones

> Piedad, piedad a mi llanto,

San Franco de Sena de Agustin Moreno

- ¿Quién es el que debería tener piedad?
  R. Indeterminado.
- ¿A qué hay que tener piedad?
  R. A su llanto.

> Ten piedad de mi llanto.

- ¿Quién es el que debería tener piedad?
  R. La deidad.
- ¿De qué hay que tener piedad? R. De su llanto.

En «Piedad a mi llanto» y «Ten piedad de mi llanto» deben usar necesariamente las preposiciones «a» y «de» en cada caso?

---

EDIT:

- Ten (tú) piedad **de** mi.
- Ten (tú) piedad **de** mis pecados.
- Ten (tú) piedad **de** mí.
- Ten piedad conmigo.
- Ten (tú) piedad **de** mi llanto.
- Ten (tú) piedad **con** su/mi persona.
- La piedad/compasión/misericordia que mostró/mostraron **para con** su persona.
- Ten(ga) piedad **con** él/ella/nosotros/nosotras/ustedes.
- Piedad **a** mi llanto.
- Pido piedad **a** mi persona.
- Pido piedad **para** un hombre ciego.
- Pido piedad **de** todos aquellos.
- Pido piedad **para con** mi persona.
- Te pido un poco **de** piedad.
- Les pido piedad...
- Le pido a Dios que tenga piedad...

Todas estas las he escuchado o leído, se supone que el CI es en/a quién afecta, beneficia o recae la acción y dice que PUEDE ir acompañado de 'a' o 'para', pero más bien acá 'a' es una forma alegórica y de acuerdo con wimi en que 'con' aparentemente no es 'jerárquica'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Tener piedad de](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=tener%20piedad%20de)" es la forma que más he oído, y la que se usa en misa en España.

> Ten piedad de nosotros, Señor Dios, perdona las faltas nuestras [...]

Pero también hay muchos ejemplos de "[tener piedad con](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=tener%20piedad%20con)" en Linguee

> Los sacerdotes no tienen piedad con los atacantes y les niegan la extremaunción.

A mi entender, "tener piedad de" se utiliza más para hablar de clemencia en una situación en la que el agente que "tiene piedad" tiene poder sobre el otro. La expresión "tener piedad con" parece utilizarse más en el sentido de "tener compasión", es decir, entender el sufrimiento de otros y no ser demasiado duro con ellos. Esto es mi interpretación, y la diferencia es pequeña.

También se encuentra bastante la construcción "[tener piedad hacia Dios](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=tener%20piedad%20hacia%20dios)", con el significado de "mostrarse piadoso ante Dios". Por supuesto, "tener piedad de" no sería correcto en este caso.

En resumen, hay distintas preposiciones que se pueden usar con "tener piedad".

Comment: No creo que "tener piedad de" sea diferente en otros países.

Comment: Lo que pregunto es si hay una regla fija para el caso en que 'ten (tú) piedad de mi' donde el agente esta claramente identificado a diferencia de donde se omite el verbo y queda el dativo con el complemento directo. Ahora que lo mencionas 'con' también lo he escuchado, pero preguntaba más bien sobre si usar 'de' o 'a' para introducir al complemento directo. 'Piedad de mi llanto' también lo he es escuchado.

Comment: También decir que la forma del primero es literario, antiguo, pero como ejemplo de gramática se rige por alguna regla si lo comparamos con 'ten piedad de' en ese mismo contexto?